# Getting this error:Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config on running "rake db:migrate" command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rake db:migrate
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.

Getting above error on running rake db:migrate.

Below are the list of gems i have installed in my system.
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.1.4, 2.3.14)
actionpack (4.1.4, 2.3.14)
actionview (4.1.4)
activemodel (4.1.4)
activerecord (4.1.4, 2.3.14)
activeresource (4.0.0, 2.3.14)
activesupport (4.1.4, 2.3.14)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.6.3)
childprocess (0.5.3)
domain_name (0.5.19)
erubis (2.7.0)
ffi (1.9.3)
hike (1.2.3)
http-cookie (1.0.2)
i18n (0.6.11)
json (1.8.1)
mail (2.5.4)
mechanize (2.7.3)
mime-types (2.3, 1.25.1)
mini_portile (0.6.0)
minitest (5.4.0)
multi_json (1.10.1)
mysql (2.9.1)
net-http-digest_auth (1.4)
net-http-persistent (2.9.4)
nokogiri (1.6.2.1)
ntlm-http (0.1.1)
polyglot (0.3.5)
rack (1.5.2, 1.1.6)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (2.3.14)
rails-observers (0.1.2)
railties (4.1.4)
rake (0.8.7)
rubyzip (1.1.6)
selenium-webdriver (2.42.0)
sprockets (2.12.1)
sprockets-rails (2.1.3)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.4)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (1.2.1)
unf (0.1.4)
unf_ext (0.0.6)
watir-webdriver (0.6.10)
webrobots (0.1.1)
websocket (1.1.4, 1.0.7)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Rake,the log as you posted in question shows rake 0.8.7 version , you might try removing it.

Install latest rake version, might be it resolve your problem